# How to shift values inside array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array with elements.
for ex - let data = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];

Now if I pass 2 in function as a parameter, then the last two value will move to first in the array.

```
 let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 functionname(data, 2);
 //Expected output - 4,5,1,2,3
```

Now if I pass 3 in function as a parameter, then the last three value will move to first in the array.

```
  let data = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
    functionname(data, 3);
    //Expected output - 3,4,5,1,2
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: @FelixKling Problem is , current code is not giving expected output.

Comment: BTW,You have 3 arguments in your function and only 2 are given in your call.

Comment: No i just tried to get my expected output bt i was unable to solve

Comment: Why do you expect the first call to move two values (`4` and `5`) to the front ?

Comment: Please forgot my code just consider my expected output and help me to achieve this.

Comment: Even with the updated requirements the expected output for the second call is wrong. Moving the last 3 values of `4,5,1,2,3` to the front will result in `1,2,3,4,5`.

Comment: @Titus-- Please check my question, i edited again.

Comment: Last time I udpated answer.. next time better precise you requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function insertAndShift(data, len) 
{
    let cutOut = data.splice(-len);         // cut <len> elements from the end
    data.splice(0, 0, ...cutOut);           // insert it at index 0
}
    
let data = [1,2,3,4,5];
insertAndShift(data, 2);
console.log(data);

data = [1,2,3,4,5];
insertAndShift(data, 3);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Immutable

```
function insertAndShift(arr, from) {
    return [...arr.slice(-from), ...arr.slice(0, arr.length - from)];
}
insertAndShift([1,2,3,4,5], 2) // [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
insertAndShift([1,2,3,4,5], 3); // [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Nice. However on defense of my answer - if you check history of this question you will find out it looked like mutability were required.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```js
function insertAndShift(arr, from) {
        let cutOut = arr.splice(arr.length - from, arr.length); 
        arr.splice(0, 0, ...cutOut);            
    }
    
let data = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

insertAndShift(data, 2)
console.log(data)

data = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
insertAndShift(data, 3)
console.log(data)
```

Comment: second argument of splice method is number of element you would like to cut, not the last index

Comment: @l00k fixed. so it cuts and shifts last `from` number of values to the begning